# How different can microclimates be than their surrounding areas?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, climate

How much different in temperature and pressure can a microclimate be than the surrounding region?  In other words, if you had a dry region but then a valley within a ring of mountains that isolated the local environment could the valley have distinctly different humidity, temperature and pressure and how far much different could it get?

Comment: https://10mosttoday.com/10-fascinating-microclimates-from-around-the-world/ or googling "extreme microclimates" (no quotes) may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Elevation is often responsible for the biggest differences; you can have snow and glaciers on the top of mountains in warm climates. South America can show you how extreme the differences in precipitation can be: rain forest on one side of the Andes Mountains, world's driest (non-polar) desert on the other. So really it depends on how high and complete your mountain ring is.
[Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=LHUZDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=plateau%20microclimate&source=bl&ots=QmEXUdFTNK&sig=0YDHV2d4TTJDJe4IzWRj8aDMHXU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipgoufs7vWAhVEbSYKHcFWA-MQ6AEIVzAN#v=onepage&q=plateau%20microclimate&f=false) is a decent book on the subject.